# Get only required file details from a HDFS directory in scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I encountered an issue while working with org.apache.hadoop.fs package in Spark Scala. I need only required file details(file name, block size, modification time) from a given directory. I tried using the following code

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileStatus, FileSystem, Path}

val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val dir: String = "/env/domain/work/latest_ts"
val input_files = fs.listStatus(new Path(dir))
```

The variable input_files obtained is Array[FileStatus] and has all the details about the files in that directory. In My Spark code, I only need the above mentioned three parameters for each file present in the form of a List[Details].

```
case class Details(name: String, size: Double, time: String)
```

In the Array[FileStatus], we have 'path' (file full path) as String, block size as Long and modification time. 
I tried parsing the Array[FileStatus] as Json and taking out required key value pairs but I couldn't. I also tried the following where I created three lists separately and zipped them to form a list of tuple (String, Double, String) but it is not matching to List[Details] and throqing an error while execution.

```
val names = fs.listStatus(new Path(dir)).map(_.getPath().getName).toList
val size = fs.listStatus(new Path(dir)).map(_.getBlockSize.toDouble).toList
val time = fs.listStatus(new Path(dir)).map(_.getModificationTime.toString).toList
val input_tuple = (names zip time zip size) map {case ((n,t),s) => (n,t,s)}

val input_files : List[Details] = input_tuple.asInstanceOf[List[Details]]
```

The error I got was

```
Exception during processing!
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple3 cannot be cast to com.main.Details
```

Could any one please advise is there a way to get the required parameters from fs or how to correctly cast the tuple I have to Details
Please help, Thanks in advance

To convert Json and read key value pairs, I converted Array[FileStatus] to String using mkString(",") and tried to parse using JSON.parseFull(input_string) which threw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileStatus, FileSystem, Path}

val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val dir: String = "/env/domain/work/latest_ts"
val input_files = fs.listStatus(new Path(dir))

val details  = input_files.map(m => Details(m.getPath.toString, m.getBlockSize, m.getModificationTime.toString)).toList
```

This will give you List[Details]. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have another small question. Is there a function that copies files between hdfs directories. like ~hadoop fs -cp command, I know fs.rename(source_path, target_path) but that will move files between folders. Thank you